# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found at java.util.Scanne

Tags: java, methods

Making this program for school final project. I am getting error when I try to run and am unsure what I need to do to fix it.
error says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)

at BusinessCardMaker.getName(BusinessCardMaker.java:41)

at BusinessCardMaker.instructions(BusinessCardMaker.java:28)

at BusinessCardMaker.main(BusinessCardMaker.java:131)
```

What am I doing wrong. What can I change to make the program better? Whats wrong with my code thats causing the errors?

Thanks to you all in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;
public class BusinessCardMaker{
    private static String wholeName;
    private static String firstLineAddress;
    private static String secondLineAddress;
    private static String company;
    private static String location;
    private static String jobTitle;
    private static int officePhoneNum;
    private static String extNum;
    private static int input;
    private static String email;
    private static int cellNum;
    private static int cardNumber;
    public static void instructions()  throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Welcome to your very own Business Card Maker");
        System.out.println("\nTo access the program please type 1");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int startProgram = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.close();
        if(startProgram == 1)
        {
            getName();
            getAddress();
            getDepartment();
            getPhoneNums();
            getEmail();
            generateCardNum();
            cardMaker();
        }
    }
    public static void getName()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input your whole name in this format (First M. Last)");
        wholeName = keyboard.nextLine();
        keyboard.close();
    }
    public static void getAddress(){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the first line of your address?");
        firstLineAddress = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the second line of your address?");
        secondLineAddress = keyboard.nextLine();
        keyboard.close();
    }
    public static void getDepartment(){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What company do you work for?");
        company = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What particular location of company do you work for?");
        location = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your primary position?");
        jobTitle = keyboard.nextLine();
        keyboard.close();
    }
    public static void getPhoneNums()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your cell phone number?");
        cellNum = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is your office phone number?");
        officePhoneNum = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Do you have and office extention? If yes enter 1, if no enter 0");
        input = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (input == 1) {
            Scanner keyboardExt = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is your extention number?");
            extNum = keyboardExt.nextLine();
            keyboardExt.close();
        } else {
            extNum = "N/A";
        }
        keyboard.close();
    }
    public static void getEmail(){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your Email Address?");
        email = keyboard.nextLine();
        keyboard.close();
    }
    public static void generateCardNum(){
        System.out.println("We automatically generated a random business card number");
        Random random = new Random();
        cardNumber = random.nextInt(1000) + 1;
    }
    public static void save() throws IOException    {
        String businessCard = "Business_Card.txt";
        File myFile = new File (businessCard);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(myFile);
        System.out.println("Your card has been saved to " + businessCard);
        writer.println("\n\n            Your Business Card");
        writer.println("\n*****************************************************************************");
        writer.println("Card Number:" + cardNumber);
        writer.println("\n"+company);
        writer.println("\n\n\n\n\n                               "+wholeName);
        writer.println("                               "+jobTitle);
        writer.println("\n\n\n\n\n");
        writer.println(location+"                                    "+"Office:"+officePhoneNum+"Ext:"+extNum);
        writer.println(firstLineAddress+"                                    "+"Cell:"+cellNum);
        writer.println(secondLineAddress+"                                    "+"Email:"+email);   
        writer.close();
        }
    public static void checkForFile() throws IOException{
    String businessCard = "Business_Card.txt";
    File myFile = new File (businessCard);
    if(!myFile.exists()){
        myFile.createNewFile();
    }
    }
    public static void cardMaker() throws IOException   {
        System.out.println("\n\n            Your Business Card");
        System.out.println("\n*****************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("Card Number:" + cardNumber);
        System.out.println("\n"+company);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n                               "+wholeName);
        System.out.println("                               "+jobTitle);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n");
        System.out.println(location+"                                    "+"Office:"+officePhoneNum+"Ext:"+extNum);
        System.out.println(firstLineAddress+"                                    "+"Cell:"+cellNum);
        System.out.println(secondLineAddress+"                                    "+"Email:"+email);          
        checkForFile();
        save();
    }
    public static void main (String[]args)  throws IOException{
        instructions();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a comment showing where the line number the error is occuring on, that would be the place to look for what is causing the error.

Comment: First off, you need to call `hasNextLine()` before fetching via `nextLine()`, since `hasNextLine()` blocks until a line is entered, which `nextLine()` consumes. Second, you shouldn't call `Scanner#close()` on a `Scanner` wrapping `System.in`, since it will close `System.in` for the remainder of the program's execution.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja `Scanner#nextLine` also blocks the thread until there is a line to read from `System.in`, so there is no _need_ to call `hasNextLine` first (if you use `System.in` as the source stream).

Comment: I think there is no need to close the Scanner, you can add an instance variable `Scanner keyboard`, and open it once. by the way , why uyour variables are `static` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyboard.hasNextLine()` has to return **true** before you call `keyboard.nextLine()`

Depending on what you really want to achieve you might want to use it like:

```
if(keyboard.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

`.hasNextLine()` is blocking passively waiting for line to appear(new line character to appear) so next solution would be to surround call to

```
keyboard.nextLine()
```

with try/catch.

Comment: `String line` should be defined outside IF statment ;)

Comment: This is correct; you need to either set it up as `if (keyboard.hasNextLine()) { line = keyboard.nextLine(); }`, or `while (keyboard.hasNextLine()) { line = keyboard.nextLine(); processLine(line); if (/* line OK */) break; }`

Comment: @OSryx maybe, or maybe not. who knows?

Comment: @zubergu right , it depends

Comment: @ShotgunNinja Well not really. This is not the solution to the problem. The exception won't occur anymore, but OP also wouldn't be able to enter something.

Comment: @Tom Yeah, but that's for a totally different reason. The OP shouldn't be calling `Scanner#close()`.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja That is right and that is his problem. He doesn't need to call `hasNextLine` first.

Comment: There's more to the problem than I originally thought. I'm turning this one into community wiki, feel free to edit it as you wish, providing more details.

Comment: @Tom With respect to the loop over `hasNextLine()` / `nextLine()`, it may be redundant, but it's more clear to the reader to include both (esp. for parity with file I/O code); in addition, it's a safe condition to be used for an input validation loop (ie. "The text you have entered is incorrect, please try again").

Comment: @ShotgunNinja It is correct, that this is clearer and more safe to check first if there is something to read, but this is _not_ the solution to the problem and that is the point I'm talking about :D. I also would recommend to call `has...` first, but in case of `System.in` there is no _need_ to do that :P. But that is just nitpicking.

Comment: @zubergu This worked! Also had some issues after this with .println statements showing up be for user input was recieved and saved to variable. Fixed this by adding extra keyboard.nextLine(); where needed.